# What smart device options do I have for poor lighting in living room?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

My living room does not have great electrical lighting. The room is about 18'x12' with a fireplace on the far, short wall.

Above the fireplace there are two angled recessed lights (can aim them in a direction, if wanted). These are far from the rest of the room and do not light up half of the room at night.

One outlet (yes, only one - which is the dumbest decision) is connected to a switch at the entrance to the room). I have two lamps connected to this which is great but we have a third lamp in the opposite corner that is not hooked up to the switch. It annoys me more than it should that I have to manually turn on this one lamp.

Are there any smart options (wifi plug or outlet, for example) that would allow me to have all three lamps turn on with the flip of the light switch? The switch and the third lamp are on different circuits, unfortunately.

Or is there any easy way to add more recessed lights or add outlets to the switched circuit?

Comment: Application of money or effort will solve the wiring issues.

Comment: Assuming the living room is on the first floor, is there an open basement with a view of the floor joists?

Comment: if you have two lamps at the one outlet and it is the only outlet what is the third lamp plugged into?

Comment: Yes the basement is open beneath the living room. The third lamp is plugged into a different outlet that's on a different circuit. It's not connected to a switch.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you are against simply re-wiring from the basement?

Comment: I'm not against it but I know that makes this a much larger job. None of the current electrical wires can be seen from the basement - all are running in between the walls.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of plug-in receivers, or controllable outlets, for the various home automation systems. Then all you need is a compatible transmitting switch, possibly battery operated.

Example: I currently have an X10 setup (cheapest home-automation product in all senses of the word cheap; adequate for playing with for now) in my living room where a remote sends signal to a receiver, which puts the signal onto the power line, which carries it to a plug-in on/off/dimmer module, which powers the swag lamp hanging from the ceiling. I could have several other receivers set to the same channel if I wanted other lamps to respond in unison with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Remote control. A two device unit, one part plugs into the wall outlet and the lamp plugs into it, and the other is a remote control. The remote can be mounted on the wall or Mobil. there are many versions of this option.

I am waiting for the price to drop on the Philips Hue system, smart phone controlled and geo tag-able.  do a youtube search for "Philips hue" and be wow'ed.